# Standardizing column values takes long time. How to optimize the process?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am trying to standardize a column value in Table **ABC**. If the part of the string that matches with the INVALID column value in **STANDARD_VALUE_TABLE table**, the corresponding valid value to be replaced.

The **STANDARDISATION Table** has some 400 values, so according to my below procedure, each col_value from ABC is checked for 400 times to replace the invalid value and after that 1 update statement runs for one col_value.

This works for me but it takes more than expected time. It takes around 30 minute for 21K records.

Can anyone suggest a other way around to improve the performance?

> ```
> set updated_col_value_v =''
> DECLARE COL_VALUE_CURSOR CURSOR for
> select col_value from ABC
> fetch next from COL_VALUE_CURSOR into @Col_value_variable
> while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
>      begin
>      DECLARE Fuzzy_invalid_value_cursor CURSOR FOR
>      SELECT INVALID_VALUES FROM STANDARD_VALUE_TABLE
>      fetch next from Fuzzy_invalid_value_cursor into @invalid_value_variable
>      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
>            Begin
>            select @Char_to_replace = VALID_VALUES  from STANDARD_VALUE_TABLE where INVALID_VALUES=@invalid_value_variable
>            if @updated_col_value_v=''
>            set @replaced_value = replace(@Col_value_variable,@invalid_value_variable,@Char_to_replace) 
>            else
>            set @replaced_value = replace(@updated_col_value_v,@invalid_value_variable,@Char_to_replace)
>
>            set @updated_col_value_v = @replaced_value
>
>            fetch next from Fuzzy_invalid_value_cursor into @invalid_value_variable
>            end
>     update ABC set updated_col_value=@updated_col_value_v where col_value=@Col_value_variable
>
>      close Fuzzy_invalid_value_cursor
>      deallocate Fuzzy_invalid_value_cursor
>
> fetch next from COL_VALUE_CURSOR into @Col_value_variable
> End
> close COL_VALUE_CURSOR
> deallocate COL_VALUE_CURSOR
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and get rid of the outer cursor. Instead of updating one row at a time with all 400 substitutions, do each substitution once, and update all the rows that need it. How safe is your table of invalid values? If you don't need to worry about sql injections, I would use something like the following inside the Fuzzy_Invalid-Value_Cursor - you are only updating the rows that have the specific invalid value, but you're doing all of them at once. Yes you may be updating some rows multiple times, but you may also be skipping some of them entirely, depends on the data, and you are only doing the replace function for rows that actually need it.

```
Update ABC Set Col_Value = replace(Col_Value,@invalid_value_variable,@Char_to_replace)
Where Col_Value like '%' + @invalid_value_variable + '%'
```

Comment: I thought of this option to limit the replace and update for only the rows which has invalid values. But in your case we need to run the update statement for each substitution. Anyway let me try this option and see how long it takes to complete. Thank Man

Comment: Well, yes, you are running 400 updates in this case. But in the previous one you are running 21K updates - one for each row, and in this version you do a lot less replace operations. If the like clause is not too slow, then I would think this should be faster - it is worth trying, anyway.